# is it possible to programatically transfer files stored on amazon s3 from one region to another?

Tags: java, amazon-s3

Does anybody know is it possible to programatically transfer files stored on amazon s3 from one region to another?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easily accomplished using the Amazon S3 API to copy the object from one bucket to another. It doesn't matter that the buckets are in different regions.

Here's an [example](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?CopyingObjectUsingREST.html) using the **Rest API**.

```
PUT /jetsam HTTP/1.1
Host: atlantic.s3.amazonaws.com
x-amz-copy-source: /pacific/flotsam
Authorization: AWS 15B4D3461F177624206A:ENoSbxYByFA0UGLZUqJN5EUnLDg=
Date: Wed, 20 Feb 2008 22:12:21 +0000
```

Or if you prefer, the **SDKs** can do the same thing. Here's a [**.Net SDK example**](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?CopyingObjectUsingNetSDK.html).

```
static AmazonS3 client;
client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(
                    accessKeyID, secretAccessKeyID);

CopyObjectRequest request = new CopyObjectRequest();
request.SourceBucket = bucketName;
request.SourceKey = keyName;
request.DestinationBucket = bucketName;
request.DestinationKey = destKeyName;
S3Response response = client.CopyObject(request);
```

If you mean that you want to change a buckets region, you would have to:

- Copy the objects to a new bucket
- Delete the old bucket
- Recreate the bucket in the new region
- Copy the objects back into the new bucket.

Of course most of the major S3 **GUI tools** can also copy objects between buckets and regions too.

Comment: <code>  s3Client.putObject(targetBucketName, key
       ,s3Client.getObject(sourceBucketName, key).getObjectContent()
       ,s3Client.getObjectMetadata(sourceBucketName, key));</code>

Comment: @aviad - I'm not sure, but that looks like you are downloading the file to your computer before uploading again to the new bucket, rather than just copying it within S3 itself.